# Delete JPA object with @OneToMany relationship in Play! Framework

Tags: jpa, playframework, persistence

I am trying to delete an object in Play! but I am getting this error:

```
PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

My guess is that there is a problem with the `@OneToMany` relationship I have declared inside.  I'm not sure, though.  Here is the declaration of my Entity:

```
@Entity
public class JumpSession extends GenericModel{
public JumpSession()
{
    sessionUID = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
//***********JPA relationships
@Id
public String sessionUID;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="jumpSession")
public List<UserJump> userJumps;

@ManyToOne
public User jumpMaster;
//**********end JPA relationships

public String inspectorUID;
public String packDetailUID;
public String aadsn;
public String aadType;
public String dropzone;
public String jumpType;
public String sessionName;
@As("MM/dd/yyyy")
public Date createdOn;
@As("MM/dd/yyyy")
public Date jumpDate;
public String startNotes;
public String endNotes;
public String notes;
public String startTime;
public int status;
}
```

When I delete a JumpSession, I need the UserJump entries to just point to null instead of a JumpSession.  Here is the simple code I'm using to delete the object:

```
JumpSession jumpSession = JumpSession.findById("blah");
jumpSession.delete();
```

EDIT:
The relevant parts of UserJump:

```
@Entity
public class UserJump extends Model{

@ManyToOne
public JumpSession jumpSession;
}
```

There are many other pieces of a UserJump that still make it unique even without a JumpSession.  Is there a way to allow the `jumpSession` reference be `null`?

EDIT:
I'm going to open a new question on this, as my question has changed. The current answer meets the original question.

Comment: What does UserJump look like?  Are there any other constraints on either the JumpSession or UserJump classes?  Is there more to that ConstraintViolationException stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your userJumps still have a reference to jumpSession. Deleting the userJumps first will solve the problem.

If for some reason you want to keep the UserJumps, then you need to remove the reference to jumpSession from userJumps

Comment: But is there no way to just allow for a `null` reference in UserJump?